# Sibling hover via css doesn't work - why?

Tags: html, css

I try to manipulate the sibling of an element by hovering its sibling element. I do it like that:

```
.sw_2-technik + .sw_2-emotionen{
    background:green;
}

.sw_2-emotionen:hover ~ .sw_2-technik{
    background:orange;
}
```

Whereas the html-structure is kinda like that:

```
<section class="wrapper">
<div class="sw_2-technik"></div>
<div class="sw_2-emotionen"></div>
</section>
```

Whilst the first operation works nicely, the second one (.sw_2-emotionen:hover ~ .sw_2-technik) does nothing. What do I do wrong there?

Thanks!

Comment: You can only target next siblings, not previous

Comment: If you want to target a previous sibling with CSS, here's a clean and simple method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sibling selectors only affect elements when the second one comes after the first on the page - not the other way around.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element **only if it is preceded by the first**, and both share a common parent.

Comment: But don't I have exact that situation? With both siblings within the same wrapper (common parent) and - though I don't know exactly what "preceded" means - the second element really follows up directly after the first one.

Or do I get something wrong there? Thanks!

Comment: @Daiaiai put `sw_2-emotionen` before `sw_2-technik` and you'll see.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio But I thought "+" was especially used for these siutations to  target an element right AFTER that one? Why should I then at all use "~"
So the plain answer is: The situation I do have is not doable without JS?

Comment: @Daiaiai the first element needs to preceed the second element on the page, as in, in the HTML source.

Comment: @Daiaiai you would use `~` if there was 1 or more elements in between the 2 elements that you're targeting.

Comment: @Daiaiai here's a CSS selectors [cheat sheet](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for you. Apologies for using W3Schools.